# Githug Gem Level Issue

Tags: ruby, github, open-source, rubygems

I am writing a level for the Githug gem, a game that teaches github https://github.com/Gazler/githug

I forked/cloned the repo and created a level called "delete_branch":

```
difficulty 2

description "You have created too many branches for your project. There is an old branch in your repo called 'delete_me', you should delete it."

setup do
  repo.init
  FileUtils.touch("README")
  repo.add "README"
  repo.commit_all("Initial commit")
  repo.git.native :checkout, {"b" => true}, 'delete_me'
  repo.git.native :checkout, {}, 'master'
end

solution do
 return true unless repo.branches.map(&:name).include?('delete_me')
end

hint do
  puts "Running 'git --help branch' will give you a list of branch commands."
end
```

I am unable to figure out how to test it and am having a hard time running the level on my local machine. Here is a link to my forked repo:

https://github.com/smilansky/githug

This is my first open source contribution, and any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, you can call ruby something like `ruby -Ilib bin/githug` to adjust where ruby is looking for "includes" (think of it as if where ruby looks for its 'required' modules).

As githug will create a directory in which you will cd, your call might actually look like `ruby -I../lib/ ../bin/githug` . I am sure there is more sophisticated solutions installing the gem in a seperate environment or stuff like that.

Otoh, the [githug github page/ its README](https://github.com/Gazler/githug) states pretty clearly how to test levels (just read till the end...).

Answer (score 0):

@Felix, thank you, I was able to figure it out - the README states to use the load command, which doesn't exist, but other contributors were using the reset command. From within the githug directory, I needed to pass in the full path:

```
githug reset ~/documents/programming/open_source/githug_project/githug/levels/delete_branch.rb
```

I submitted my pull request last night and Gazler already responded to me :)